# Assign color to text in website based on ID in database

Tags: javascript, python, mysql, django

In my forums website, I want to assign a certain color to each role. For example the admin color is blue, so the username of this admin is always blue. In my database, I'm using MySQL, I have a role table that assigns an ID for each role and a users table linked to the role table.

How can I assign the color I want to the role ID that I want?

*Note: I'm using Django for my back-end work*

Thank you.

This is what I've tried so far.

```
<div class="username"> <a id= "usercolor" style="color: white; cursor: pointer;"
 onclick="openmodal( {{ instance.author.id }})"> {{ instance.author.Username }}
 </a>
 <script>
  {% if instance.author.Role.RoleName == "Admin" %} 
     document.getElementById("usercolor").style.color="blue";
  {% endif %}
 </script>
 <br>
</div>
```

I assigned a default color white to the username inside the forum and gave it an id. I then took the RoleName column in my userrole table from the database and using if statement and document.getElementById I tried to make it that only the admin color is blue. This only changed the color of the first admin [as shown in the image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/clhX2.png)

Comment: Hi bachar97, What code have you written so far, and what specific part of the problem do you need help with? Do you need help getting the value 'blue' out of the database? Or is it a problem with taking that value from the code and applying it to the CSS on your page?

Comment: @C_Z_ Hello, the color isn't in the db, I just need to give this role a certain color but the linking has to be by the ID in the database. It's like a javascript function using getElementByID but this time the ID of the database.

Comment: Have you made any attempt to do this on your own? If so please show what you are doing. Otherwise, look at javascript objects.

Comment: @CharlesBamford I haven't written anything useful yet. I have no clue if I can assign a function in JavaScript based on the database ID. And I'm a beginner in Django so I didn't really get far with that too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own post even though delayed. I used Django instance and an if condition for each role ID as follows:

```
{% for instance in item %}
<div class="post">
    <div class="body">
        <div class="authors">
            <div class="row">
                <img class="account-info-sub2" style="border-radius:50%" src="{{ instance.author.user_thumbnail.url }}" alt="error">
                <div class="username"> <a class="{% if instance.author.Role.RoleName == 'User' %} shimmeruser {% elif instance.author.Role.RoleName == 'Admin' %} shimmeradmin {% elif instance.author.Role.RoleName == 'Forum Moderator' %} shimmermoderator  {% elif instance.author.Role.RoleName == 'Customer Service' %} shimmerservice {% endif %}" style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="openmodal( {{ instance.author.id }})"> {{ instance.author.Username }} </a>
                    <br>
                </div>
                <div class="rolemob">
                    <div class="account-info-sub2">{{ instance.author.Role.RoleName }} </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

As you can see in the if condition, if the author of the post has a rolename of Admin his colour should be the one assigned in the "shimmeradmin" CSS. "author", "Role" and "RoleName" are all from the database. Ignore the div tags, they're not wrong I just didn't copy the whole code obviously.
To summarize. What you need to do understand is this line of code:

```
<div class="username"> <a class="{% if instance.author.Role.RoleName == 'User' %} shimmeruser {% elif instance.author.Role.RoleName == 'Admin' %} shimmeradmin {% elif instance.author.Role.RoleName == 'Forum Moderator' %} shimmermoderator  {% elif instance.author.Role.RoleName == 'Customer Service' %} shimmerservice {% endif %}" style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="openmodal( {{ instance.author.id }})"> {{ instance.author.Username }} </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript lets you assign keys and values in arbitrary pairs. For instance, you could set your role/color combos with a structure like this:

```
const roleColors = {
  admin: "goldenrod",
  moderator: "purple",
  notableTroll: "olive",
}
```

This would let you get the color associated with a role, such as admin with

```
const adminColor = roleColors.admin;
```

or, assuming you had a user object with a role property shaped like

```
{
  username: "JimNaysium",
  role: "admin"
}
```

you could get the user's role with

```
const adminColor = roleColors[user.role];
```

If you want to have this in a function, instead of a direct lookup, you could do something like:

```
function getColorByRole(role) {
  const roleColors = {
    admin: "goldenrod",
    moderator: "purple",
    troll: "olive",
  };
  return roleColors[role];
}
```

Good luck and happy coding.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! How can I apply this to the database though? Because the admins for example are all in the database. So I want them and each new admin to share the same colour.

Comment: you have role table you can assign color for each role to apply for all role as example for admins

Comment: You probably shouldn't apply this to the database. If a user is an admin, your frontend can make them goldenrod. If you want to change what color that is, all you have to do is change the string in the javascript project. If you were to put the color in the database, you would have to update the database to change colors.

Comment: I understand but doesn't doing it in the database makes it easier for newly assigned admins?

Comment: Where do you expect to see the color?

Comment: @CharlesBamford If you mean in the interface, I want the username of the admins to be blue. If you can see I edited my post with the code that I tried and the output that I got.